# Copy tooltip to clipboard

Tags: java, tooltip, clipboard

I have a Java program with icons, tooltips...
What I need is that every time a tooltip is showed, the containing text should be copied to the windows clipboard.

Any solution should be a general single solution for all the tooltips. I cannot change the properties of each one of them (there are thousands...)

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Swing and `JComponent#setToolTipText(String)`?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, if you are indeed using Swing, you might need to subclass your components and override `createToolTip()`:

```
class MyJButton extends JButton {

    @Override
    public JToolTip createToolTip() {
         return new MyJTooltip();
    }

}
```

And:

```
class MyJTooltip extends JToolTip {

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean aFlag) {
        super.setVisible(aFlag);
        //copy your text to clipboard here
    }

}
```

Not very practical, not very pretty, but I can't think of another way right now: AFAIK, there is no way to subclass [TooltipManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ToolTipManager.html) and make it be used as the default.

If you are using JavaFX, things get much easier:

```
new Button().setTooltip(new MyJavaFxTooltip());
```